# How do I properly update the WordPress database password?

Tags: database, mysql, security, password

A site that I manage was recently compromised, and I am going through the steps to harden and re-secure the site. I would like to change the MySQL database password and want to make sure I do not take the site down (for more than a minute).

I am also concerned that if I manually change the database password directly in the **wp-config.php** file that it will be visible and un-encrypted. For example, if my initial password at install was "*please*" it would display in the **wp-config.php** file as "*aDQps4txy*".

So what is the best way to go about updating the database password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is technically challenging. WordPress *must* have access to your DB password in plain text. Having access to the `wp-config.php` contents is already a breach of security in progress.

There are alternate approaches to configuration, such as loading credentials via environment variables, but in practice they are used exceedingly rarely because PHP's configuration file is a reasonable solution already.

It's not clear why you assume someone will get access to the configuration file. As a low-hanging fruit, you can place it outside of the web accessible directory. WordPress will scan for the configuration file up one directory level above itself. For subdirectory installs, you could use `require` to load configuration content from elsewhere, but even that is rarely done.

Comment: I am not sure what was compromised, so I want to be cautious and update the password. Once I opened the file I saw it looked like it had been encrypted with MD5 hash (based on what I have read in searches). If the only way to update it is to just update the password right there in the config file (with no encryption) then that is what I will do. But having seen that it's encrypted prompted me to ask the question.

Comment: @ChasesWork I am not entirely sure about your situation. MD5 isn't reversible (by purpose at least) and isn't suitable for encryption in a first place. It's not a common practice to have database password in `wp-config.php` to be encrypted in any way.

Comment: It's very possible I am just misunderstanding all of this. My confusion lies in that the DB password in the config file is not the actual DB password.

Comment: If that was the case your site _wouldn't work_. :) You might be looking at the wrong configuration file or you might have more than one valid set of database credentials.

Comment: I can assure you I am looking at the live config.php file on the server. I'm realizing it is a moot point because the server is basically toast if they get access to that right? I do appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual DB password is stored unencrypted in the `wp-config.php`, i.e., if your password is `foobar`, the corresponding line in `wp-config.php` is:

```
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'foobar');
```

As @Rarst pointed out:

> Having access to wp-config.php contents is already breach of security in progress.

This is because PHP is a hypertext **preprocessor**. Anyone who accesses `wp-config.php` via their web browser will have the file routed through the **server-side** PHP interpreter. The interpreter passes only those data onto the client (the web browser) that it has been instructed to output. The DB password is not outputted by PHP. When I access my `wp-config.php` through my browser, I get an empty page with no source code at all because this file does not output anything at all.

However, it is not true that having the DB password stored unencrypted is completely risk-free. Anyone who gets the chance to bypass the PHP interpreter and hence read the file's source will gain access to your password. This is also what @Rarst meant. To be clear, this can also be a **man-in-the-middle** who is eavesdropping on your **unencrypted FTP connection**. The moment you download `wp-config.php` through an insecure FTP connection (in contrast to an encrypted SFTP connection) in order to edit it and re-upload it again to your server, the possibility your password being spied on **does exist**.

The easiest way to prevent most attacks is to keep your server up-to-date through security updates and to ensure to always use secure protocols (HTTP/FTP over TLS = **HTTPS/FTPS** instead of HTTP/FTP, alternatively **SFTP**, and **SSH** instead of Telnet) when dealing with sensitive data, i.e. when acting as administrator.

Read more on https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress.

Comment: The blog post moved to [https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/). As Frank seems to have left the building, can someone else update it?

Answer (score 0):

One way this stuff can be exposed without CLI access is if the PHP module in Apache is absent or broken for whatever reason. In that case, it just dumps the raw PHP. I've not tested this recently; this was a few years ago. But it is not cool.

Technically, since WordPress is open source, you can just do something like this:

`` define('DB_PASSWORD', '`cat /etc/wp_db_pass | base64 -d`'); ``

to create a safer place for the WordPress password file. In this example I'm assuming you created the password like so:

```
echo 'mypassword' | base64 > /etc/wp_db_pass
```

However, if you don't have commandline access you might be able to do something similar over FTP.

Comment: Yep, if you are not running PHP it may jjust as well be text.